# Swift Decodable for a list or items of mixed types

Tags: swift, list, decodable, mixed-type

In a couple of apps that I've been working on lately, I need to read a list of items of mixed types. A good example of a "real-life" situation would be a list of items in an article: there is a title, a subtitle, body text, images etc.

I've come up with something like this:

```swift
// Sample data:
//
// {
//    items: [
//         {
//             "type": "a",
//             "a": "This one is A"
//         },
//         {
//             "type": "b",
//             "b": "This one is B"
//         }
//     ]
// }

import Foundation

// MARK: - "Root" protocol for all decodable items

protocol Item: Decodable {}

// MARK: - Items

struct ItemA: Item { let a: String }
struct ItemB: Item { let b: String }

// MARK: - Extractor

/// Helper for extracting items
struct ItemExtractor: Decodable {
    
    enum TypeKey: String, Decodable {
        case a
        case b
    }
    
    let item: Item
    
    // MARK: - Decodable compliance
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case type
    }
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let type = try values.decode(TypeKey.self, forKey: .type)
        
        let itemValues = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        
        // In particular, looking to eliminate this `switch`
        switch type {
        case .a:
            item = try itemValues.decode(ItemA.self)
        case .b:
            item = try itemValues.decode(ItemB.self)
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - Container

/// Container of items
struct MyList: Decodable {
    let items: [Item]
    
    // MARK: - Decodable compliance
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case items
    }
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        
        let extractors = try values.decode([ItemExtractor].self, forKey: .items)
        items = extractors.map { $0.item }
    }
}
```

- The type of an item in the data file is marked up with a "type" field;
- The **ItemExtractor** helper reads the type and inits an item according to it's type;
- Those items are then taken from the ItemExtractor array and added to the list of items in the MyList struct.

Now the question: is there a way to generalize this code to avoid the **switch** statement in the ItemExtractor, which would be especially useful if there is a lot of different types of items, or, perhaps, there is a different approach altogether?

Looking forward for a better solution,
–Baglan

Comment: I think the only way to eliminate the switch statement is to use a dictionary instead of the switch. I don't think there is any way to know what type "a" or "b" is

Comment: For your real life example, wouldn't it be better to have a type Article with properties for title, subtitle etc instead?

Comment: @Schottky yes, maybe some sort of an introspection together with naming conventions.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson maybe for a title, but imagine a situation when an article has several blocks of text, images and video in an order that is not defined ahead of time and needs to be constructed from the data.

Comment: Arrays and optional properties? Order of properties is not important.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson that's a great solution if you only have a couple of types of items and those items don't have a lot of fields, in fact, that's what I had done initially, but this approach has a potential of becoming rather unwieldy as the project grows. Besides, this would require some additional processing when, say, a view for the item is being created.

Comment: I think having a generic data structure and custom decoding logic will not be much better if any.